# Finding eigenvalues of covariance matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

suppose there is some bivariate normal distributed data and I want find the eigenvectors of its covariance matrix. Somehow the eigenvectors I calculate do not fit to the data, is there something wrong in my code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import scipy.linalg as la

# Generate a positive-definite covariance matrix & generate data
A          = np.random.random([2,2])
cov_given  = np.dot(A,A.T)
mean_given = np.random.random([2])
data       = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_given,cov_given,10000)

# Find the numerical mean and covariance, diagonalize
mean = np.mean(data, axis = 0 )
cov  = np.cov(data.T)
w, v = la.eig(cov)

# Plotting procedures
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xmin, ymin = np.min(data,axis=0)
xmax, ymax = np.max(data,axis=0)
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:.01, ymin:ymax:.01]
pos  = np.dstack((x, y))
ax.contourf(x,y, multivariate_normal(mean=mean, cov=cov).pdf(pos))
ax.plot([mean[0], mean[0] + v[0][1]],[mean[1],mean[1] + v[1][1]])
ax.plot([mean[0], mean[0] + v[0][0]],[mean[1],mean[1] + v[1][0]])
ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
plt.show()
```

[image: data with bad covariance eigenvectors]

First I thought, I intermixed the columns and rows of v, but as it turns out, it does not work better. Do you spot the problem?

Comment: With this random data, some plots look okay, and others are off. Could this just be a floating point precision error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem.  The vectors are being found correctly (check it with `v[:,0].dot(v[:, 1])`, which is 0 if they are orthogonal).  That's the check that matters.  You can see this in the plot by setting the aspect ratio to one using

```
xmin, ymin = -3, -3
xmax, ymax = 3, 3
```

Comment: Yes, and it took me longer than I care to admit to realize a visual check is not appropriate in this situation.